# One answer to multiple questions?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, answers, self-answer

Some time ago I created these two questions: "[How to build nested responses in an Apigility driven application with a ZfcBase-DbMapper based model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810799/how-to-build-nested-responses-in-an-apigility-driven-application-with-a-zfcbase)" and "[How to access and manipulate data in Apigility before it is sent to the client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588475/how-to-access-and-manipulate-data-in-apigility-before-it-is-sent-to-the-client)". The first one is mor general, the second one refers to a concrete way of the solution. Anyway, the questions don't duplicate each other.

Now I've finally found a solution for the second question and it's also a possible solution for the first one. I want to post it as answer. Is it allowed to post the same solution for diferent questions? If not -- why?